# PhoneGap/Cordova “javac -version” not found on Windows 8

Tags: java, android, cordova

Can somebody help me sort the problem out ?
[image: Javac -version not found on windows 8]

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. What is your problem? What have you already tried to solve it?

Comment: it suggest you don't have jdk installed or in classpath... try `javac -version` and see if its there, else install it/put in class path.

Comment: You have JRE not JDK installed. That's why you can get `java -version` but can't find `javac`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add you java directory as `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables or add you java directory at the end of `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\Arnold\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\framework\project.properties`

Change `19` to `17` under target android.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-17
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```